# Error - Redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: magento-1.7

Not getting proper path for Codeignitor code in Magento.  Magento works absolultely fine.

Mixed Content: The page at https/test.com/test  was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://www.test.com/'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 4):

If you edit the secure/unsecure base url for you Magento based site you may find yourself locked out of both the frontend and admin sections of the site

Log to database using phpMyadmin

Find the table labelled core_config_data

Edit the rows entitled web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url

Edit the row web/url/redirect_to_base to 0 instead of 1

clear session and cache using ftp var/cache and var/sessions folders.

Comment: Edit the row web/url/redirect_to_base to 0 instead of 1

clear session and cache using ftp var/cache and var/sessions folders. - this worked fo me

Answer (score 1):

Check your URLs within your configuration. If any of the secure URLs starts with http:// or if any of the unsecure URLs has that, while the base URL starts with https:// then that's your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually it was server level error. Our server is hosted by CntrlS. Someone from there modified file and now it is rectified.